# Unix Updating binary file with C

Tags: c, file, unix

I have an assignment that is meant to simulate updating a database of customer accounts. We are meant to use low level system calls, `read` `write` and `lseek` to update a binary file that is to contain `structs` of `unsigned` accountNumbers and `double` account values.

I have it working right now where I can "initialize" the account if the account doesn't already exist in the binary file, but my issue is understanding how to update the account if it's an existing account. I.e, how can I read the contents of the `double` already in the binary file into a buffer, add (or subtract) a value grabbed from another text file stored as a `double` and rewriting back to the binary file the new value.

I'd share some code I have already written, but to be honest, my brain can't figure out how to actually store the old `double` value taken from the binary file as a `double` that is able to have addition or subtraction performed on it. Any hints, guidance, example code would be super appreciated!

Comment: `read(&mydouble, sizeof mydouble, fd);`

Comment: AH! I was writing it to a char array and not double. Thank you so much my friend! @wildplasser

Comment: BTW: I had the order of the arguments permuted. The manual is your friend.

Comment: Note that you'll read the record (to make sure you've got the right account number), modify the data in memory, seek back to where the record starts, and write the revised data.  Or you make a new copy of the file, editing records before writing to the new file, and then, when you're finished, you take steps to rename the old file, rename the new file, and think about removing the old file.

Comment: Thanks for the information @JonathanLeffler!